# What is the current (2023) state of using internationalized email addresses?

Tags: email, smtp, internationalization

Digging through SO and Google, I'm trying to figure out what the current state is regarding the use of internationalized email addresses. Best SO answers were from 2021. Based on my research here's what I understood:

Domain Part: Unicode characters can already be used for the domain part of an email address. These characters are automatically encoded into "internationalized domain names" (IDNAs) using a well-defined algorithm.

Mailbox Part: Unicode characters can be used for the mailbox part of an address (e.g., eric@mail.com) only when using the SMTPUTF8 protocol. SMTPUTF8 protocol provides full Unicode support for email addresses. However, the problem is that, as of 2021, the adoption of the SMTPUTF8 protocol was not yet widespread enough. If any server in the message delivery chain does not support SMTPUTF8, the sender has to fallback to regular SMTP and convert the email mailbox name to its ASCII alias using some heuristics that the receiving end is using. These heuristic rules are not standardized, and the sender would need to know exactly how the receiving end is doing the aliasing. Therefore, this solution does not generalize well.

So, if I understood correctly, this means that we can already use Unicode characters for domain names, but for the mailbox part, everything becomes a question of "How good is the general support for SMTPUTF8?"

Is this reasoning correct, and how good is the support for SMTPUTF8 currently (in 2023)?

Comment: You could check the capabilities advertised by common SMTP servers to see. As an aside, based on my personal experience with my own SMTP server software (which doesn't support the SMTPUTF8 extension), the only UTF8 messages rejected by it are all spam, so I wonder if this is a reason support has not ramped up as much...

Comment: Thanks for insights! I'm not very familiar with SMTP servers and email protocols in general. The trigger for my question was that few of our customers would like to use utf8 emails as their account username. So far we haven't enabled this option because we are unsure whether we could contact these customers reliably :D. So I was looking for some kind of "Can I use..." rule of thumb for unicode email addresses.

Comment: I don't think there's a single answer anyone can give you. However, in your case, you can find out. I'm assuming you know all your customers' email domains. Look up the MX servers for all those domains (the email domain itself may not necessarily be the mail server). Then, telnet to port to 25 on that host, and the greeting should give you a list of capabilities. If you see SMTPUTF8 for all your customers, you should be good. If not, then there isn't 100% support. Also be aware that it's not just SMTP, IMAP by default is 7-bit and has extensions that need to be supported for UTF8

Comment: Thanks, great info! It's always nice to learn something new :) It seems that though enabling unicode emails _could_ be possible, for our purposes it's too fragile and tedious and would also need quite deep knowledge on email protocols etc. However, there shouldn't probably be problem to allow unicode domain names in email addresses. AFAIK support for IDNAs is already very wide